# Check for illegal Characters in any input or text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

After help from here where the solution works in the fiddle in the simplest form. But while implementing it, it does not work. So I have added the actual code with the solution given previously.

What I am trying to do is check for illegal characters in any of the input box and text area? Fiddle with actual code is here. [**Actual Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/reQrL/4/)

```
$('.formsubfree').click(function () {
var str = $(this).prevAll("input, textarea").first().val();
if (/[%&<>\[\]{}]/.test(str) === true) {
    alert('These characters & < > [ ] { } % are not allowed.  Please remove them and try again.');
}
});
```

Earlier Solution with the stripped out html is here  in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AR323/7/)

Thanks

Comment: It would help to see the HTML structure you have in play here as well. I see two potential problems: 1) your inputs and textareas are nested in something, and they don't have the same immediate parent as the submit button; 2) if #1 isn't the case, you're still just getting the first matched element's value, so if there are no illegals in the first matched element, you won't get true.

Comment: You whole html is badly skewed. Please first learn html. Even the color coding of the editor can tell you if you are going the right way. Here is something I have sorted out in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gq5j4/ Work on that.

Comment: `$(this).prevAll("input, textarea").first().val();` is giving undefined

Comment: I am afraid, the html is auto generated and I have no control over it. ..;o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, with your current HTML, would be:

```
$('.formsubfree').click(function () {
    var invalid = ['%', '&', '<', '>', '[', ']', '{', '}'],
        validate = $(this).prevAll(':input').first();
    if (/[%&<>\[\]{}]/.test(validate.val())) {
        console.log("Yeah, these characters ('" + invalid.join(', ') + "') aren't allowed. So stop it.");
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AR323/8/).

Or possibly:

```
$('.formsubfree').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission of the form
    var validate = $(this).prevAll(':input').first(),
        found;
    if (/[%&<>\[\]{}]/.test(validate.val())) {
        found = validate.val().replace(/[^%&<>\[\]{}]/g,'').split('').join("', '");
        console.log(found);
        console.log("Yeah, these characters '" + found + "' aren't allowed. So stop it.");
    }
    else {
        // if no errors were found, submit the form:
        $('.formsubfree').closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AR323/11/).

References:

- [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks..your code works in fiddle and it does not work when I implement it...arrgghhhh...

Comment: You're welcome! ...um, any errors in the console? Have you tested that the variables are being populated correctly (particularly the `validate`)?

Comment: When I copied html/js in notepad and tried it there and get this. 

Saved as special-charcter.html > opened in FF > Entered Test& in the first input box and clicked save and the url changes to special-character.html?ANSWER.ID.MENU.1.=Test%26&DUM_FIXT.2=&ANSWER.ID.MENU.2.=Save&ANSWER.ID.MENU.18.=&DUM_FIXT.19=&ANSWER.ID.MENU.20.=&DUM_FIXT.21=&ANSWER.ID.MENU.22.=&DUM_FIXT.23=

Comment: So the `form` is being submitted?

Comment: Updated the final code-block to address that problem (though it would've helped if you'd included the `form` itself (with its relevant parts) in the question. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41708/discussion-between-19eggs-and-david-thomas)

Comment: Any ideas..?? Am very frustrated.

Comment: I'm afraid not, currently, and I'm way away from keyboard, now; so while I may be able to look tomorrow it's not something I can attend to right now, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: Hi! David, 

Thanks no worries. Can you take a look using this code in the fiddle as it is the closest to the implementation code. ? http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/reQrL/4/

Comment: Hi! David,
Just wanted to let you know that I solved it. I was not looking at the  html properly. And preveAll() threw me at the wrong direction when I should have used closest. Working copy here http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/reQrL/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can use validator method with custom rules like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element) {
                            return this.optional(element) || value === "NA"
                                            || value.match(/^[0-9,\+-@.A-Za-z ]+$/);
                    }, "Please enter a valid character");
```

It will discard all the characters except 0-9, A-Z, a-z, @,+,-and .

Comment: I assume we need to use the validator plugin, which we can't..any ideas thoughs..